# Regarding 2 factor authentication and adding new devices. Which one of these is safer?

Tags: multi-factor

Let's say I have a mobile device with google authenticator which uses TOTP, which I use everytime to log in into my personal accounts.

If I want to add a second device. I would need to have access to the secret token. But If I don't have it, I'd need to disable 2 factor authentication for a couple of minutes and then re-enable it to activate it on both of my devices.

Another method would be storing my secret key, So in case I need it in the future, I would not have to disable 2 factor authentication

So my question is:

Which is safer?

1. Disable 2 factor authentication and re-enabling it every time I add a new device (which allows the potential attacker a time frame to access to my personal accounts)
2. Store secret keys in a safe place and use them every time I add a new device without the need of disabling 2 factor authentication (An attacker could potentially steal them)

Comment: You mention this *safe place* you will be storing the keys, where is this exactly?

Comment: Encrypted on a local backup or phisycally on paper

Comment: Can you have a new key generated? Or do you get one key and its permanent?

Comment: I can do both, it's part of the question I asked.

Comment: In your question you mention that you are using the **same** key as generated in the first connection. My question is: Can you generate a new one when you want to connect a new device (Without enabling-disabling)?

Comment: I am assuming generating a new one without enabling-disabling is not possible.